# Can BSoD be reliably detected?

Tags: windows, crash, event-log, crash-dumps, bsod

I'd like to reliably detect that a BSoD happened. I see three ways of doing it:

1. Check the existence of a crash dump or whether the event 1001 was
   emitted, but the problem is that both can be disabled by user
2. Check whether event 41 was emitted, but when the crash dump file
   isn't generated this event won't provide the bug check details
3. Create a driver that registers a bug check callback, but I believe
   this callback, because it executes at *HIGH_LEVEL*, won't be able to
   write to a file or registry so I can retrieve this information after
   reboot.

Am I correct about 3? Is there another way to get this information?

Comment: For 1) "can be disabled by the user": it should be in the system log, so that user must have administrator access. If he has administrator access, he can control the whole machine, so he could also uninstall a driver

Comment: To me, this might be an XY-problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to have this information (whether a bug check happened or not) regardless of user settings. I'm asking here to know if Windows saves this information elsewhere, or if I'll depend on the user's configuration.

Comment: Ok, so you implement all 3 techniques to have the highest likeliness of detecting the BSOD. You could run Windows in a Hypervisor and detect if the client OS crashes. Not sure if you should do this, though.

Comment: It looks like there isn't a reliable way to do it. I've posted the same question in the [NTDEV list](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=276996), there are valuable comments there.